# Unable to Dual Boot Windows 8 ( 64bit ) and ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, easybcd

I bought new Asus Laptop with DOS and installed windows 8.1 64bit and then i installed Ubuntu 12.04 but as with other os my boot options does not show windows 8 and ubuntu

Then i tried EasyBCD now windows 8 and ubuntu is show but when i click on ubuntu it agains boots and ubuntu now starts agains boot option came

Comment: When you were installing ubuntu, did you include the windows boot manager. coz if you didn't then your quite lucky to actually see windows. Try reinstalling Ubuntu but this time add windows boot manager on installation

Comment: can you tell me how i can include windows boot manager on installation

Comment: when you were installing Ubuntu, didn't it ask you to select which boot loader to include..? There must have been that step. It's been long since i installed ubuntu but that option exists. try a dry run installation to check

Comment: there was not such options that it ask me to select boot loader I have installed ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Is there anyone to solve this problem

Comment: Can you boot into Ubuntu...?

Comment: Sorry but please look here for a [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

Comment: no i cannot boot into ubuntu. even the option is not shown in bootmenu at startup only windows 8 is shown there

Comment: Please read the guide on the link i gave you. it should help you.

Comment: sorry to say but there is no new thing in the guide. My ubuntu every time installs succesfully in my F drive but it is not appearing in boot menu i have windows8 in c drive

Answer (score 0):

### Ok here's one

1. Backup all your data to some external drive
2. Assuming you already have Windows installed on your system.
3. Install Ubuntu from your medium preferably flash-drive
4. Restart your PC to complete the installation
5. Boot into Ubuntu and run a grub update

   **sudo update-grub**

from the terminal and it should detect and add the windows bootloader to the grub. Then you can now reboot and you should see windows listed in the grub menu.

if it doesn't go well, download [bootrepair](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/?source=navbar) and run make a bootable flash from it and boot up with that flash plugged in to your system. Attempt to run a repair .

Try that and tell me how it goes.

Comment: first of all i am trying this and sudo update-grub not working . It says this command not found

Comment: and i Have a bootable pendrive and it boots ....It install the linux and restart after proper installation but after that ubuntu is not appearing in boot options

Comment: reinstall your grub like this **sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub** then try that command again

Comment: tried but it fetch some files then gives error 'unable to fetch some archives

Comment: is this err such a big one

Comment: Ok, I suggest that you reinstall everything starting with Windows then Ubuntu on separate partitions. how about that.?

Comment: No No ....i can't I am developer i have all my tools installed on windows and i have some project to do in ubuntu but i don't even think so that it will create such a time consuming problem

Comment: Then i suggest you repair windows with an installation disk

Comment: my windows is still working why to repair it

Comment: so you can login to windows, you didn't mention that.?

Comment: i can login.........plz tell me how we can dual boot with both. this is official forum of ubuntu still none can tell proper installation steps for dual boot